# `DragBox` cannot show when selecting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, openlayers

I defined a `DragBox` in `Vue` with `Openlayers` like this:

```js
      this.dragBox = new DragBox({
        condition: platformModifierKeyOnly,
        style: new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: [0, 0, 255, 1],
          }),
        }),
      })
      this.map.addInteraction(this.dragBox)
```

```css
<style scoped>
.ol-dragbox {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-color: rgba(100, 150, 0, 1);
}
</style>
```

But when I start to use it to select, it doesn't show on the screen but there are some features selected indeed. How can I make the dragbox show on the screen when selecting features? Thanks!